# How to disable warning messages in Maya?

Tags: python, warnings, maya

I am working on a script to clean models' attributes and vertices' values using Pyhton.

One of the functions for this script involves the command "cmds.makeIdentity".
Depending on the model, this command creates a warning message saying "Warning: Freeze transform with negative scale will set the 'opposite' attribute for these nodes: blahblahblah".

In my case, it is OK to set the 'opposite' attribute for those nodes, so I just want to get rid of those warning messages so the people who might use this script won't worry about it.

I've been searching for the maya API and Open maya and so, but I can't find a way to just disable a warning message inside a script. Is there any way to do it? And also, is there any way to do it using python only?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can ignore warning messages unless via the script editor preferences, but you can instead print an empty string to virtualy hide it to the user:

```
cmds.warning()
print '',
```

The comma will remove the carriage return of the print so it won't even print an empty line.

Comment: Yes I guess that is one way to avoid the warning to be seen to the user... Thank you!